# Implement bottom up search algorithm in Python NLTK Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, nltk

I am working with NLTK Parented Tree structures to have access to parent nodes and to left and right siblings.

In the first step I have to iterate over the nodes in a bottom-up fashion: I always start with the V (verb), and then go the tree until I reach Root(SENT).

**[Look at my tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEge9.png)**

At every parent (VN and SENT) I have to check if their children are nodes ending with ***. The VN of the tree in the image doesn't have any child, so I keep going up. SENT has two children ending with ***\, so I create a new tree (the one on the left).

So, what I want to do (iteritavely) is:

1. Grow structure from the leaves to the root (add parent nodes ) starting from V tags.
2. Check at every point (at every parent node) if children nodes have labels ending with ***. If so, create a new tree that represents the verb and the labels that we just searched. These labels keep their order: note that NP-S*** comes before NP-O***

I've been thinking what would be the pythonic way to do this and if I can do this with Parented Trees at all.

Parented Tree keeps telling me I cannot insert a tree that already has a parent. Is there another way to access parents AND siblings?

Here the stuff that I've tried. Still pretty far from the tree I want to create -

```
def CreateVerbTree(tree):
    for tree in tree.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.height()==2):
        if tree.label()=="V":
        newtree = ParentedTree(tree.parent().label(), [tree.copy()])
        print(newtree.parent())
        print([x for x in newtree.subtrees()])
        return newtree

Test:
VerbTree(tr)

None
[ParentedTree('VN', [ParentedTree('V', ['read'])]), ParentedTree('V', ['read'])]

(VN (V read))
```

I would really appreciate if someone tells me his approach to extract the tree in the left. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you for the editing, Mayur H

Comment: I am trying to find a solution. Just want to point out that your **left** tree left out the PONCT subtree is that intentional? Or did you forget to add it ?

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, it's intentional, because the tag doesn't end with ***

Comment: Anyone? Any ideas?